# Going "Stateless" and loading scripts dynamically

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, stateless

What I want to know is if I am approaching this from the right angle.

I have an asp.net app I am building.  I am using a Masterpage for the overall look of the app (below you can see the code).

I'd like to have the menu system use a dynamic load like jQuery's `.load()` function to load the content.  That is fine and I have that down.  The `.load()` function uses `innerHTML` to pump that content into the page.  This is a problem if on that page you want to load module specific scripts and styles.

My question is, in an environment such as this, how do you guys load your scripts for these modules? Should I load every script on the initial load of the app? This app will not ever be "that big" however I want to make sure I do it right just in case.

**MasterSheet**

```
<div id="primaryNavigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="../Default.aspx">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Modules/Page1.aspx">Some Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Modules/Page2.aspx">Reporting</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Modules/Page3.aspx">More Reporting</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Modules/Page4.aspx">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="mainContentContainer">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphBody" runat="server" />
</div>
```

**Example Module inside of the Content tag**

```
<div id="container"> 
    Inside a page

    <script id="scriptToLoad" type="text/javascript">
      alert('Something');

      head.ready(function () { console.log('please print'); }); 
    </script>

</div>

<div id="includeScripts">
    ../Files/Javascript/SomeModuleSpecificJs.js
    ../Files/Javascript/SomeModuleSpecificJs1.js    
</div>
```

My idea was to set up a `div` in each module that would have the id of "includeScripts" and load those from a method within the mastersheet like this.  This method works (needs some tweeking obviously) however if the user keeps clicking on modules eventually every file will be loaded. If thats the case I might as well load them all on the mastersheet.

**JS to be ran when the MasterPage is loaded**

```
$navigation = $("#primaryNavigation").delegate('ul li a', 'click', function () {
                    $('#primaryNavigation').find('li').removeClass('current');
                    $(this).parent().addClass('current');

                    $('#mainContentContainer').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #container');

// Obviously this would overwrite the content from the container, this is merely proof of concept
                $('#mainContentContainer').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #includeScripts');

                    var jsArray = $('#includeScripts').text().trim().split("\n");

                    $.each(jsArray, function (index, value) {
                        $.getScript(value);
                    });

                    return false;
                });
```

Comment: Wow, still only one answer. Maybe try making another question that's more generic ("How can I...") and analyse any offered code snippets.

Comment: did you mean masterpage?  I don't know what a mastersheet is...

Comment: @phillip Yes, masterpage... sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about `.load()`, but JQuery's `.html()`, `.append()`, and a few other related functions will automatically run any script tags that they find in the given HTML. If `load()` doesn't do that for you, it should be easy enough to use `$.get(..., function(){$('#myElement').html();});` instead. You could even write your own extension specifically for this purpose.

Style sheets may be a different story. I've typically just used a single style sheet per page.

#### Edit

I just spent some more time reading your question, and I realized that I didn't answer it fully.

> Should I load every script on the initial load of the app?

It really depends on the size of your scripts and the way you expect users to interact with your system. In [this seminar](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/architecting-performance-gwt.html), the people who made Google Wave talk about how they addressed this issue. At one point the speaker says, "Perceived latency is the most important thing to optimize for."  The problem was, in an early version, their javascript file (optimized and compiled by GWT) was a few megabytes in size. People with a slow connection (a cell phone browser, e.g.) would have to wait a long time for all this code to download before they could see what was in their Inbox. Their solution was to create "split points" in their code so that it could be loaded in chunks. The code necessary for displaying the Inbox could be loaded first, whereas the Contacts panel could wait until the user clicks "Contacts."

But you can take this too far. The other speaker in this video says the time spent in loading falls largely under one of two categories:

- Fetching data you don't need, and
- Too many HTTP requests

Each HTTP round-trip involves a certain amount of overhead, so it can be worthwhile to load *some* code you don't need yet in order to avoid having to make another round-trip in a few milliseconds when you realize you need it.

Since you say:

> This app will not ever be "that big"

... I'm guessing that you'll probably fall mostly under the latter category (too many HTTP requests). The best thing to do in that case is:

1. Use a tool like [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) to consolidate all your javascript files into a single file (which can be automatically minified when not in Debug mode).
2. If your application has a login page that doesn't use all this javascript functionality, add a `script` tag for this javascript file at the bottom of the login page so that the user's browser will download the file behind the scenes while the user is busy entering their username and password. The master page for the rest of the site should simply include the script file once in a standard `script` tag.
3. Make sure your site's caching rules are set up properly so that user's browser will only request this file once.
4. Make sure your site is set to compress this javascript file since javascript (especially minified javascript) lends itself to gzip compression very nicely.

Once you've done this, you should find that there is no "perceived latency" from loading your javascript file.

If your application does eventually become "that big," you'll want to break your program down into modules like the Google Wave team did. But choose your modules based on how you expect the system to be used. If only a small handful of users is likely to use your admin interface, for example, you'll want to put all of your admin UI code into a separate module that "normal" users will never have to download.

When deciding where to draw the line, UI experts basically say one-fifth of a second is the point where the typical human's brain starts wondering, "Did that work?" If a user clicks a button and has to wait longer than that before they see something happen, you've reached the point of "perceived latency." Anything beyond that will become increasingly annoying to the user.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, would your answer change on some of these points if I mention that this wouldnt be an external facing app? So all users would be on the same internal network. Just trying to get a feeling for how other devs do this type of thing.

Comment: @Mike Fielden: If it's only being used on a local network, you probably have higher speeds and lower latency, but probably not by orders of magnitude. It means you'll get a little farther with the single javascript file approach before the file starts causing perceived latency, but the overall reasoning doesn't change.